# How to increase the width of the entire plot using ggplot2 R

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2, label

I've been using ggplot2 to plot a graph which looks like a heatmap with the right most and top most rows and columns respectively showing the sum of its elements. However, it's a huge dataset and all the "sum" numbers are squeezed into it with no clarity. I'd like to widen the plot so that the labels look readable. Here's my code so far.

```
mat <- read.csv("trial.csv",sep = ",", header=T, row.names=1)
vec <- as.vector(as.matrix(mat))
varieties = names(mat)
matVar = matrix(vec, ncol = length(varieties), nrow = length(attr(mat, "row.names")))
library(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
library(grid)
require(grid)
mat$id <- rownames(mat)
gg <- melt(mat)
#mat$id <- reorder(mat$id)
#gg$id<-factor(gg$id)
gg$id <- as.character(gg$id)
gg$id <- factor(gg$id, levels=rev(unique(gg$id)))
ggplot(gg, aes(y=variable,x=id))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red",high="white")+
  geom_text(aes(label=value), data=cbind(aggregate(value~variable, gg, sum), id="total")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value),data=cbind(aggregate(value~id, gg, sum), variable="total")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  scale_y_discrete(limits=c(levels(gg$variable), "total"))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(levels(gg$id), "total"))+
  coord_flip()+labs(y = "Patients", x= "Genes")
```

Here's sample data, but my actual dataset is really huge.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9
a, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1
b, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
c, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
d, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
e, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
f, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
g, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
h, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
```

This is the output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying dimensions of your graphic device e.g.

```
pdf(file="plot.pdf",width=11,height=8)
```

PDF uses dimensions are given in inches, while PNG in pixels, so you also may need to specify the resolution e.g.

```
png(file="animals45.png",width=400,height=350,res=45)
```

for more info see:

- http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html
- http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/10-tips-for-making-your-r-graphics-look-their-best.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, although it's a bit of a hack. Since you are using factors, and you've turned off the horizontal axis, you can add extra labels in `scale_y_discrete(...)`.

```
ggplot(gg, aes(y=variable,x=id))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red",high="white")+
  geom_text(aes(label=value), data=cbind(aggregate(value~variable, gg, sum), id="total")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=123456789*value),data=cbind(aggregate(value~id, gg, sum), variable="total"),hjust=0) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  scale_y_discrete(limits=c(levels(gg$variable), "total","",""))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(levels(gg$id), "total"))+
  coord_flip()+labs(y = "Patients", x= "Genes")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. My question wasn't clear. I'm sorry. I could get the right hand side numbers perfectly. However, I have issues with the upper numbers. This could be because of the very thin lines in the plot which I'm not able to fix. I'd really appreciate if you could help me do that.